# Remotely login to Linux System with java and run "grep"

Tags: java, linux, ssh, asterisk

I have a linux server running an asterisk, and I want to know it is restarted or what's happening in the server so i wrote a java app to read console. Like here (http://www.coderanch.com/t/556707/java/java/connect-Linux-Java-code); it is a really good example.

But there is a problem here:

```
      String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));      
  host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

  Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
   UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
   session.setUserInfo(ui);  
   session.connect();

   String command=  "asterisk -rvvv | grep 'Disconnect' ";

   Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec"); 
   ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

   channel.setInputStream(null);

   ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

   InputStream in=channel.getInputStream(); 

   channel.connect();
 while(in.available()==0){  
      int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);  
      if(i<0)
      {break;}
      System.out.print("-"+new String(tmp, 0, i));  

    }
```

When I execute `asterisk -rvvvvv | grep 'Disconnect`, it gives me a blank row, and this code reads to console row by row. So if I get any data after this blank row, nothing gives me. Program sticks over there. So i need to read 2nd line after a blank line.
[image: console example]
or any idea to read this 'Disconnect' string?

My main purpose -  "did asterisk restart?" - because when asterisk restarts, gives a string like this, and we don't know why asterisk restarts!

Comment: Try [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Comment: already i am using JSch :D

Comment: Hmm, and from the Examples Shell and Sudo did not offer similar functionality?

Comment: it is connection with ssh and the main problem that black line. program cannot pass other line or wait for other line. so when it gets  blank line(gives int=0) dont wait for other lines. well i will think about another way later. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can use: `asterisk -rvvvv | grep -v ^$ | grep 'Disconnect'`
grep command will remove the blank lines

Answer (score 0):

I am using jsch to. You need to wait enough time to get buffer ready SO need to use  try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}. At least I am using like that.

```
 while(true){
        while(in.available()>0){
          int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
          if(i<0)break;
          System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if(channel.isClosed()){
          System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
          break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
      }
      channel.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it is what i want. problem is blank line so it gives me in.read(tmp,0,1024)=0 so never ever can read below row/line.